# Random exception on Web service call

Tags: c#, rest, web-services

I have a Web service which works fine in production environment.
But sometimes (randomly) an exception is raised :

> à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n à
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n à
> fctSendRequestSynchrone[T](String sRequest, enumHttpMethod eMethod,
> Object oParams)\r\n à API.csRestApi.d__0`1.MoveNext()"

Here is my code :

```
.........

//Here is the line which raises the exception :
fctSendRequestSynchrone<string>(string.Format("logs/{0}/message", _lIdLog), cs.enumHttpMethod.POST, oLogLigne);

.........
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private T fctSendRequestSynchrone<T>(string sRequest, csRestApi.enumHttpMethod eMethod, object oParams = null)
{
Task<T> otask = SendRequest<T>(sRequest, eMethod, oParams);
return otask.Result;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public async Task<T> SendRequest<T>(string sAction, enumHttpMethod eMethod, object oParams = null)
{

string sResponse = string.Empty;
T oValue;

using (var oClient = new HttpClient(new LogginHandler(_oCnx, new HttpClientHandler())))
{
oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string sRequest = string.Concat(_sUrlApi, "/", sAction);

if (_oToken != null)
{
oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(_oToken["token_type"], _oToken
["access_token"]);
}

using (HttpResponseMessage oResponse = await oClient.PostAsJsonAsync(sRequest, oParams))
{
if (oResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
HttpContent content = oResponse.Content;
sResponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
{
throw new RestApiException(oResponse);
}
}

}

oValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sResponse);

return oValue;
}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Eric

Comment: Please provide full exception, there is only a part of stacktrace

Comment: You are probably deadlocking because you use `.Result` on a call that `await`s an async call.

Answer (score 0):

Roman Kalinchuk, Crowcoder : thanks for your replies.
Roman Kalinchuk :
Here is the entire stacktrace :

```
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   à logs.csLogWS.fctSendRequestSynchrone[T](String sRequest, enumHttpMethod eMethod, Object oParams)\r\n   à logs.csLogWS.sbrErrorLigneRejet(String sMessage, String sCdRejet, Exception oException)\r\n   à logs.csLogWS.ligneLogInformation(String sMessage)\r\n   à Importation.Program.sbrImportUnitaire(String sCdInfImp, String sFileNameIn, String sFileStructure, String sLiProcedure, String[] args)|   à Service.API.csRestApi.<SendRequest>d__0`1.MoveNext()".
```

I simplified it in my preceding question post.
The application is on production environment, do I have to put pdb files on production server in order to get more stacktrace ?

Crowcoder : do you mean that .Result is waiting while SendRequest is waiting too ? What would you suggest ?